# Partially mask data of a group of number using regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to partially mask data using regex. Here is the input :

```
123-12345-1234567
```

And here is what I'd like as output :

```
1**-*****-*****67
```

I figure out how to replace for the last group but I don't know to do for the rest of the data.

```
String s = "123-12345-1234567";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{2})", "*")); // output is *23-***45-*****67
```

Also, I'd like to use only regex because I have different type of data, so different type of mask. I don't want to create functions for each type of data.

For example :

```
AAAAAAAAA // becomes ********AA

12334567 // becomes 123******
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You could simply change the character at index `i` to an asterisk for each index in the array `[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Strings in Java are immutable, so we can't really do that.

Comment: @Tim, how about creating a new string whose ith character is the ith character in the original string or an asterisk, depending on whether the index is in the array in my first comment?

Comment: Java probably gets a much lower grade than Ruby or Python when it comes to beautiful and concise string manipulation syntax.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the thing is that i want to use only regex because I have different type of data, and I don't want to create different functions for each type of data

Comment: zozo, I guess I don't understand the *rule* for where to put the asterisks if the string is not necessarily 3 digits, a hyphen, 5 digits, a hyphen, 7 digits.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Here is the rule for this one :
The first group is always 3 digit (replace by * the 2 last digits)
The second is always 5 digit (replace by * the 5 digits
The last groupe is always 7 digit (replace by * the 5 first digit)

Comment: @zozonenete you should detect type of pattern and replace each type by mapper between type to regex of replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java supports a fixed quantifier in a lookbehind, so what you might do is use a pattern with an alternation to account for the different scenario's if you must use a regex only.

Using the lookarounds you can select a single character to be replaced by `*`

**Note** that this is hard to maintain, and it would be a better option to write separate functions for the different data formats using separate patterns or string functions (perhaps accompanied by unit tests)

```
(?<=^\d{3,7})\d(?=\d*$)|(?<=^[A-Z]{0,6})[A-Z](?=[A-Z]*$)|\d(?<=^\d{2,3})(?=\d?-\d{5}-\d{7}$)|\d(?<=^\d{3}-\d{1,5}(?:-\d{1,5})?)
```

The separate parts match:

- `(?<=^\d{3,7})\d(?=\d*$)` Match a digit asserting 3-7 digits to the left and only digits to the right
- `|` Or
- `(?<=^[A-Z]{0,6})[A-Z](?=[A-Z]*$)` Match A-Z asserting 0-6 chars to the left and only chars A-Z to the right
- `|` Or
- `\d(?<=^\d{2,3})(?=\d?-\d{5}-\d{7}$)` Match a digit asserting 2-3 digits to the left and optional digit, - with 5 digits and - with 7 digits to the right
- `|` Or
- `\d(?<=^\d{3}-\d{1,5}(?:-\d{1,5})?)` Match a digit asserting 3 digits to the left followed - and 1-5 digits and optionally - with 1-5 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zUG5F6/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OsQxt3)

```
String regex = "(?<=^\\d{3,7})\\d(?=\\d*$)|(?<=^[A-Z]{0,6})[A-Z](?=[A-Z]*$)|\\d(?<=^\\d{2,3})(?=\\d?-\\d{5}-\\d{7}$)|\\d(?<=^\\d{3}-\\d{1,5}(?:-\\d{1,5})?)";

String s1 = "123-12345-1234567";
String s2 = "AAAAAAAAA";
String s3 = "12334567";

System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(regex, "*"));
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(regex, "*"));
System.out.println(s3.replaceAll(regex, "*"));
```

Output

```
1**-*****-*****67
*******AA
123*****
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following regex replacement approach:

```java
String input = "123-12345-1234567";
String output = input.substring(0, 1) +
                input.substring(1, input.length()-2).replaceAll("\\d", "*") +
                input.substring(input.length()-2);
System.out.println(output);  // 1**-*****-*****67
```

Here we concatenate together the first digit, followed by the middle portion with all digits replaced by `*`, along with the final two digits.

**Edit:** A pure regex solution, which, however, is more lines of code than the above and might be less performant.

```java
String input = "123-12345-1234567";
String pattern = "^(\\d)(.*)(\\d{2})$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    String output = m.group(1) + m.group(2).replaceAll("\\d", "*") + m.group(3);
    System.out.println(output);  // 1**-*****-*****67
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with only one replaceAll, without the substring ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  In other languages, such as Python, we could have used a regex callback function to avoid the substring operations.  Java doesn't really have this though.

Comment: The thing is that i want to use only regex because I have different type of data, and I don't want to create different functions for each type of data. For example, AAAAA will become AA***

Comment: @zozonenete I have given you the regex option.  I find it uglier than the substring version I gave.  Your call as to which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("123-12345-1234567".replaceAll("(?<=.{1,})\\d(?=.{3,})", "*"));
    System.out.println("AAAAAAAAA".replaceAll(".(?=.{2,})", "*"));
    System.out.println("12334567".replaceAll("(?<=.{3,}).", "*"));
}
```

output:

```
1**-*****-*****67
*******AA
123*****
```